# How to stop playing song and play new song

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am developing app,I have a problem that when i click on button then selected index song starts but i want to stop this song and want to play next song which index I give then,both songs start playing. means previous continuous and next also playing .
Please guide me how i stop previous song and next only start playing.
Code is here

```
  - (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    [self.audioPlayer stop];
    self.audioPlayer = nil;
    self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    if(self.audioPlayer.playing ==YES)
    {
        self.audioPlayer.delegate=nil;
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        self. audioPlayer=nil;
        NSLog(@"plat");
    }

    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:sound.text ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    //self.audioPlayer = nil;
    [self.audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
   -(void)playSound
{
     NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:sound.text ofType:@"mp3"];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:
                            [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
     [self.audioPlayer play];    
}
    - (IBAction)play:(id)sender
    {
    if (self.audioPlayer.playing == NO) 
    {
     [self playSound]; 
    }
     else
         if (self.audioPlayer.playing == YES) {
             [self.audioPlayer stop];
             [self playSound]; 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK use [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that use to play a number of items in sequence.

```
NSString *secondPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"s1" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSString *firstPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"s2" ofType:@"mov"];


AVPlayerItem *firstVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstPath]];
AVPlayerItem *secondVideoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:secondPath]];

self.queuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstVideoItem, secondVideoItem,nil]];
[self.queuePlayer play];
```